# Python request stream don't iter all contents

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using Request library to get content over HTTP.

My code is like this:

```
r = requests.get('http://blabla/mybigfile', headers={"Range":"bytes %d-%d"%(fromByte, toByte)}, stream=True)
bytesRead=0
with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
        fd.write(chunk)
        bytesRead=bytesRead+len(chunk)

if bytesRead<(byteTo-byteFrom):
    print "WHAT??? WHY???"
```

The problem is that sometime request can't iterate all chunks and total read bytes are less than expected.
Why?

These are response headers:

```
{'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
 'cache-control': 'max-age=28800',
 'connection': 'close',
 'content-disposition': 'attachment',
 'content-length': '262144',
 'content-range': 'bytes 262144-524287/339619249',
 'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
 'date': 'Sun, 07 Sep 2014 19:04:01 GMT',
 'etag': '"1491643023"',
 'expires': 'Mon, 08 Sep 2014 03:04:01 GMT',
 'last-modified': 'Thu, 04 Sep 2014 13:59:44 GMT',
 'server': 'lighttpd'}
```

**REAL CODE**

```
def downloadPart(self, byteFrom=0, byteTo=0, async=True):
    tname = threading.currentThread().getName()
    if byteTo is 0:
        byteTo = self.fileSize - 1
    print "Thread %s: download from %d to %d" % (tname, byteFrom, byteTo)

    self.req = requests.get(self.url, headers={"Range":"bytes=%d-%d" % (byteFrom, byteTo)}, stream=True)
    required = int(self.req.headers["content-length"])

    b = byteFrom
    bytes = 0
    chunksize = 8 * RemoteFile.KB

    with open(self.filename, 'r+b') as fd:
        fd.seek(b)
        for chunk in self.req.iter_content(chunksize):
            if self._stop: 
                print "%s: stopped" % tname
                return

            fd.write(chunk)
            fd.flush()
            os.fsync(fd)
            dsize = len(chunk)
            bytes = bytes + dsize
            b = b + dsize

            self.lock.acquire()
            self.progress = self.progress + dsize
            self.lock.release()
            # print  "%s: %d [%d%%] @ %f KB" % (tname, b, self.getProgressPerc(), self.getDownloadSpeed())

    if bytes < (byteTo - byteFrom):
        print self.req.raw.tell()
        print "End thread: %s: less required size %d instead %d" % (tname, bytes, byteTo - byteFrom)
        return self.downloadPart(b, byteTo, async)
    else:
        print "End thread: %s, downloaded %d bytes" % (tname, bytes)

    self.lock.acquire()            
    if self.currentByte < self.lastByte:
        if async:
            self.threads.remove(threading.currentThread())
            t = self.createThread(self.currentByte + 1)
            if t: t.start()
    else:
        print "Download complete!"
        self._complete = True          
    self.lock.release()
```

Comment: The server doesn't *have* to satisfy the whole range. There could also be compression involved (which can make a response *larger*). What are the headers on the response?

Comment: Header of response say me that content-length is exactly byteTo-byteFrom, so i expect to read all bytes in range.

Comment: What *other* headers are there? Any transfer encoding?

Comment: Thanks; just trying to eliminate possible factors. Not in a position just now to investigate why this happens (on mobile); if you don't get any answers I'll try and reproduce.

Comment: Follow-up question: what does `r.raw._fp_bytes_read` state has been read after the loop finishes? And can you determine what part of the data appears to be missing here?

Comment: Oi, why are using `fromByte, toByte` in the headers for the request, but then *test* with `byteTo-byteFrom`? Those variables do not match anywhere.

Comment: This is not my real code, i write a piece of code here, so is a simple typo error. I try to test r.raw._fp_bytes_read now. Thanks

Comment: You could use `r.raw.tell()` instead; it just returns that value too.

Comment: r.raw.tell() print the size expected to be downloaded, but real bytesRead are less thank this value.

Comment: Then your `bytesRead` handling is flawed, because `r.raw.tell()` is the number of bytes that `requests` received.

Comment: Yes but my bytesRead is the sum of size of received chunks, so this is the real number of bytes written in the file... where is the mistake?

Comment: I have added my real code

Comment: So how does your code prevent multiple threads seeking and writing at the wrong locations?

Comment: Can you add a debug print to show any chunk that is smaller than the chunk size? And use `r.raw.tell()` calls to see where your calculation goes off.

Comment: seek on file is safe in my code, mybe self.req=... is the mistake :)

Comment: There are no chunk smaller than chunksize, but there are not enough chunks received. I think the problem is that i overwrite self.req each time oi create new thread...

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it too.